# Text field becomes very small

Tags: flutter, dart

When I click on the text field, the second text field becomes very small
[image: Here is GIF:]

[image: Here is the first code:]

[image: Here is the second code:]

Comment: Try wrapping the `textformfilelds` in a `SingleChildScrollView()`

Comment: @MendelG, this will throw the following error: https://imgur.com/a/dDWrZQY

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the code as _text_, not as an image.

Answer (score 0):

Change the flex value of first expanded widget to 1 instead of 0.

**Edit**

Remove expanded from both the widgets. In first text field add maxLines : 1 and in second textfield add maxLines : null.

Comment: Then it will look like this: https://imgur.com/a/F56TANF

Answer (score 0):

Remove Expanded Widgets from both TextField and Wrap main Column to **SingleChildScrollView** to avoid getting overFlow errors